# How to find element using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

So basicly I have this HTML code:

```
    <td class="google">
        <a href="#">I love my job
    </td>
```

and I want to search in the web if there is really a link "I love my job".

So I used this xpath to find that:

```
"//td[@class=google]//a[text()='I love my job']"
```

But it is not workink for me.

What should be the xpath code ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What tool are you using to execute the XPath? Please detail how it isn't working.

Comment: I am sorry. I run this code xpath code and there was no element like this found

Comment: I am using WebDriver.findElement()

Comment: your `a` tag is not closed...

Answer (score 1):

That's because the text value of your link is not `'I love my job'`, but `'I love my job\n '`.

Use `normalize-space()`.

```
"//td[@class='google']//a[normalize-space(text())='I love my job']"
```